# BootStrap Table-How to stop b-table from re-sorting immediately on data update?

Tags: bootstrap-4

After sorting the b-table, if the data in the table is modified then the table will resort automatically.
How to stop b-table from re-sorting immediately on data update?

Comment: Are you using bootsap datatable? please share  the code

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to disable ordering

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
"ordering": false // false to disable sorting (or any other option)
});
});
```